# Define new layout with Assemble and keep generated files as same directory as default layout

Tags: generator, assemble

Hello i create applications wich i need to define the new layout for now i use in my grunt file this code

```
assemble: {
  pages: {
    options: {
      flatten: true,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/{,*/}*.hbs'
    },
    files: {
      '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs']
    }
  }
},
```

Now i read docs http://assemble.io/docs/Layouts.html and i put nessesary code like this.

```
assemble: {
  pages: {
    options: {
      flatten: true,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/{,*/}*.hbs'
    },
    files: {
      '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs']
    }
  },
  simple: {
    options: {
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/simple.hbs',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/{,}*.hbs'
    },
    files: {
      '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/simple/*.hbs']
    }
  }
},
```

Basicly i declare new layout simple and try to force generated templates to be in same dir but result is - dist/src/templates/pages/simple/name_of_file.html
This code works in default but not in other layouts.

Any help ? Is this possible i have workaround but will be nice to get this things done.

Nevermind i found a solution

```
assemble: {
  pages: {
    options: {
      flatten: false,
      expand: true,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/{,*/}*.hbs'
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: '<%= config.dist %>/', ext: '.html'}
    ]
  },
  simple: {
    options: {
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/simple.hbs'
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/simple/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: '<%= config.dist %>/', ext: '.html'}
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: if you want you can post the solution as an answer, then if no one posts a better one just mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure i just wait 8 hours because the site rules.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here is the answer

```
assemble: {
  pages: {
    options: {
      flatten: false,
      expand: true,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/{,*/}*.hbs'
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: '<%= config.dist %>/', ext: '.html'}
    ]
  },
  error: {
    options: {
      flatten: false,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/error.hbs'
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/error-pages/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: '<%= config.dist %>/', ext: '.html'}
    ]
  },
  login: {
    options: {
      flatten: false,
      assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
      data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
      layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/login.hbs'
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: '<%= config.src %>/templates/login-pages/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: '<%= config.dist %>/', ext: '.html'}
    ]
  }
```

I create 2 new layout one for error pages and one for login pages all pages are generated in same dir.